Dropdown Menu Gets Hidden Inside Scrollable Navigation Bar with overflow-x: auto
I'm working on a navigation bar with a list of items, some of which have dropdown menus. The list is too long to fit on the screen horizontally, so I used overflow-x: auto to make it scrollable. This part works perfectly fine, and the navigation bar scrolls as expected.
However, I'm encountering an issue where the dropdown menu becomes invisible when hovering over a navigation item. To fix this, I tried setting overflow-y: visible, but it's still not working. The dropdown remains hidden, clipped by the overflow of the parent container.`


.section-wrapper {
  overflow: visible;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}


.section-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
}

.nav-menu .menu {
  width: -moz-max-content;
  width: max-content;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav-menu .menu .menu-item {
  position: relative;
}
.nav-menu .menu .menu-item a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--color-text-2);
  font-weight: 500;
}
.nav-menu .menu .menu-item a:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.nav-menu .menu .menu-item.menu-item-has-children > a::after {
  content: "▼";
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}
.nav-menu .menu .menu-item.menu-item-has-children:hover > .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
.nav-menu .menu .menu-item.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.nav-menu .menu .menu-item.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu .menu-item {
  width: 180px;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
}
.nav-menu .menu .menu-item.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu .menu-item a {
  padding: 10px;
}
.nav-menu .menu .menu-item.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu .menu-item.menu-item-has-children {
  position: relative;
}
.nav-menu .menu .menu-item.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu .menu-item.menu-item-has-children:hover > .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
.nav-menu .menu .menu-item.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu .menu-item.menu-item-has-children > .sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 1px; /* Small gap to avoid overlap */
}
<nav class="section-header-sec-nav">
    <div class="nav-menu section-wrapper">
        <div class="menu-header-2-container"><ul id="menu-header-2" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-44"><a href="http://phantom777.local/sample-page/" aria-current="page">ICC Men’s</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-45" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-45"><a href="http://phantom777.local/sample-page/" aria-current="page">ICC Women’s</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-46" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-46"><a href="http://phantom777.local/sample-page/" aria-current="page">Leagues</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-47"><a href="http://phantom777.local/sample-page/" aria-current="page">Prediction</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-52"><a href="http://phantom777.local/sample-page/" aria-current="page">Match Prediction</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-48" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-48"><a href="http://phantom777.local/sample-page/" aria-current="page">Fantasy Cricket</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-49"><a href="http://phantom777.local/sample-page/" aria-current="page">Match Odds</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-50"><a href="http://phantom777.local/sample-page/" aria-current="page">ICC Ranking</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-51"><a href="http://phantom777.local/sample-page/" aria-current="page">Analysis</a></li>
</ul></div>    </div>
</nav>



` Issue:
When I hover over the nav item with a dropdown, the dropdown menu gets cut off and is not visible due to the overflow-x: auto setting on the parent container. Setting overflow-y: visible doesn't resolve this issue.
